# Managed Metadata for search categories

Tags: document-library, managed-metadata, sharepoint-search

Good morning! I have a situation to tackle: for each item in a library, there are additional columns whose values will be populated with information (strings). There's several columns - for example:

- **Column** -- Value
- **DocumentCode** -- ABC
- **AssociatedColour** -- Red

I have created these column titles as metadata tags in the MMS.

Then, I am hoping to configure the Search Service Application to search using those columns. So users can search specifically within the **AssociatedColour** field value for all documents that are labeled as **Red** or some other value.

Am I approaching this situation correctly? Can Search filter by column values? I understand that the document libraries itself function similar to a Filtered Excel document, but for an end user, it's not visually friendly.

***Update: Additional information - the values in the columns are not predetermined. For example, a user can make up a new colour ("Tomato") and enter into that field. Can MMS be configured to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can do this. There are two ways to "Search" for this information. Since you have created the columns and crawled the content you now need to create a refinable managed property for each column. Then perform a full crawl to populate the property. When you create the property you have to decide the behavior. If you want a query for "red" to return items tagged with red, make the Managed Property "Searchable", if you only want specific property queries to return the item, for example `AssociatedColor:Red` then make the Managed Property Queryable. For all of the properties I would make then Refinable.

Once you have done that you can edit the search results page and add the three properties as Refiners. Then when users search and get results containing the items above they will be able to further refine the result by Associated Color etc.

Comment: Hey, Matthew: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation! That makes things a lot easier. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad it helped!